# Testing Spring MVC annotation mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

With Spring MVC, you can specify that a particular URL will handled by a particular method, and you can specify that particular parameters will map to particular arguments, like so:

```
@Controller
public class ImageController {

   @RequestMapping("/getImage")
   public String getImage( @RequestParam("imageId") int imageId, Map<String,Object> model ) {
      model.put("image",ImageService.getImage(imageId));
   }

}
```

This is all well and good, but now I want to test that an http request with an imageId parameter will invoke this method correctly.  In other words, I want a test that will break if I remove or change any of the annotations.  Is there a way to do this?

It is easy to test that getImage works correctly.  I could just create an ImageController and invoke getImage with appropriate arguments.  However, this is only one half of the test.  The other half of the test must be whether getImage() will be invoked by the Spring framework when an appropriate HTTP request comes in.  I feel like I also need a test for this part, especially as my `@RequestMapping` annotations become more complex and invoke complex parameter conditions.

Could you show me a test that will break if I remove line 4, `@RequestMapping("getImage")`?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you mean "How to create Unit test for Spring MVC Controllers that use annotation mapping?"?

Comment: Sorry.  I mean that I want to test that the annotation is correct, and that an HTTP request really will invoke this method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) and its `handle` method programmatically. This will resolve the method for the given request and execute it. Unfortunately this is a little indirect. Actually there is a private class called `ServletHandlerMethodResolver` in AMHA that is responsible for just resolving the method for a given request. I just filed a [request for improvement](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5763) on that topic, as I really would like to see this possible, too.

In the meantime you could use e.g. [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org) to create a mock of your controller class, expect the given method to be invoked and hand that mock to `handle`.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/users")
  public void foo(HttpServletResponse response) {

    // your controller code
  }
}
```

Test:

```
public class RequestMappingTest {

  private MockHttpServletRequest request;
  private MockHttpServletResponse response;
  private MyController controller;
  private AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter;


  @Before
  public void setUp() {

    controller = EasyMock.createNiceMock(MyController.class);

    adapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
  }


  @Test
  public void testname() throws Exception {

    request.setRequestURI("/users");

    controller.foo(response);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
    EasyMock.replay(controller);

    adapter.handle(request, response, controller);

    EasyMock.verify(controller);
  }
}
```

Regards,
Ollie

Comment: Add an extra line: `request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.INTROSPECT_TYPE_LEVEL_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);` It is needed when you are using controller level mapping

Answer (score 7):

Ollie's solution covers testing the specific example of an annotation but what about the wider question of how to test all the other various Spring MVC annotations.  My approach (that can be easily extended to other annotations) would be

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.ModelAndViewAssert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({/* include live config here
    e.g. "file:web/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
    "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" */})
public class MyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;
    private MyController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
       handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
       // I could get the controller from the context here
       controller = new MyController();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
       request.setRequestURI("/users");
       final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, 
           controller);
       assertViewName(mav, null);
       assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType(mav, "image", Image.class);
    }
}
```

I've also written a [blog entry about integration testing Spring MVC annotations](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/03/integration-testing-of-springs-mvc-annotation-mapppings-for-controllers/).