# Any open source Spring sample project that's bigger than PetClinic?

Tags: spring, open-source, spring-mvc

I've finished reading the spring doc and the PetClinic sample project. Just like to see some bigger real world project that's done with Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[Spring Projects](https://spring.io/projects)

[Powerstone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powerstone/)

[Tudu Lists](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tudu/)

[Alfresco Content Management](https://www.alfresco.com/products/community/download)

[SpringSide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/springside/)

[Plazma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plazma/)

[agileexpress](http://sourceforge.net/projects/agileexpress/)

[Zksample2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zksample2/)

[Spring Rich Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spring-rich-c/)

[Broadleaf Commerce](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce)

[OpenERP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/theopenerp/)

[HISPACTA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hispacta/)

[Luigi Open Search Engine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cw-search/)

[JOSSO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/josso/)

[HSE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hse/)

[Java Small Business Platform](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsbp/)

[jrecruiter](http://code.google.com/p/jrecruiter/)

Comment: I gives you UP vote (+1) just because you have done a really good google search about Spring based projects.

Comment: This complied list is a copy paste from my notes that I maintain as reference

Answer (score 19):

I work for a big health insurance company where we heavily use Spring in backend. I will show you how a **modularized** application is built.

**Skeleton** *WEB-INF* without classes directory

```
ar
    WEB-INF
        web.xml
        /**
          * Spring related settings file
          */
        ar-servlet.xml
        web
            moduleA
                account
                    form.jsp
            moduleB
                order
                    form.jsp
```

**Skeleton** *classes* directory

```
        classes
            /**
              * Spring related settings file
              */
            ar-persistence.xml
            ar-security.xml
            ar-service.xml
            messages.properties
            br
                com
                    ar
                        web
                            moduleA
                                AccountController.class        
                            moduleB
                                OrderController.class
            br
                com
                    ar
                        moduleA
                            model
                                domain
                                    Account.class
                                repository
                                    moduleA.hbm.xml
                                service
            br
                com
                    ar
                        moduleB
                            model
                                domain
                                    Order.class
                                repository
                                    moduleB.hbm.xml
                                service
            ...
```

Notice how each package under *br.com.ar.web* **matchs** *WEB-INF/view* directory. It is The key needed To run convention-over-configuration in Spring MVC. How to ??? rely on [ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html)

**WEB-INF/ar-servlet.xml** Notice basePackage property which means look for any *@Controller* class under *br.com.ar.view* package. This property allows you build modularized @Controller's

```
<!--Scans the classpath for annotated components at br.com.ar.web package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.ar.web"/>
<!--registers the HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter required to dispatch requests to your @Controllers-->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="basePackage" value="br.com.ar.web"/>
    <property name="caseSensitive" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Now let's see, for instance, AccountController

```
package br.com.ar.web;

@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Qualifier("categoryRepository")
    private @Autowired Repository<Category, Category, Integer> categoryRepository;

    @Qualifier("accountRepository")
    private @Autowired Repository<Account, Accout, Integer> accountRepository;

    /**
     * mapped To /account/form
     */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequesMethod.GET)
    public void form(Model model) {
        model.add(categoryRepository().getCategoryList());
    }

    /**
     * mapped To account/form
     */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequesMethod.POST)
    public void form(Account account, Errors errors) {
        accountRepository.add(account);
    }

}
```

How does it work ???

Suppose you make a request for http://127.0.0.1:8080/ar/**moduleA/account/form**.html

Spring will remove the path **between** context path and file extension - highlighted above. Let's read the extracted path **from the right To the left**

- *form* method name
- *account* unqualified class name **without** Controller suffix
- *moduleA* package which **will be added** to *basePackage* property

which is translated to

```
br.com.ar.web.moduleA.AccountController.form
```

Ok. But how does Spring know which view to show ??? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287037/default-formview-for-simpleformcontroller/3287607#3287607)

And about **persistence** related issues ???

First of all, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934753/avoiding-secondary-selects-or-joins-with-hibernate-criteria-or-hql-query/2935998#2935998) how we implement repository. **Notice each related module query is stored at its related repository package**. See skeleton above. Here is shown ar-persistence.xml Notice **mappingLocations** and **packagesToScan** property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd  
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dataSource" resource-ref="true">
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <util:list>
                <value>classpath:br/com/ar/model/repository/hql.moduleA.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>classpath:br/com/ar/model/repository/hql.moduleB.hbm.xml</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <util:list>
                <value>br.com.ar.moduleA.model.domain</value>
                <value>br.com.ar.moduleB.model.domain</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Notice i am using Hibernate. JPA should be properly configured.

**Transaction management and component scanning** ar-service.xml Notice **Two dots** after *br.com.ar* in aop:pointcut's expression attribute which means

> Any package and sub-package under br.com.ar package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.ar.model">
    <!--Transaction manager - It takes care of calling begin and commit in the underlying resource - here a Hibernate Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:advice id="repositoryTransactionManagementAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="add" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="remove" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="update" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" propagation="SUPPORTS"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <tx:advice id="serviceTransactionManagementAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <!--Any method - * - in service layer should have an active Transaction - REQUIRED - -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* br.com.ar..service.*Service.*(..))"/>
        <aop:pointcut id="repositoryPointcut" expression="execution(* br.com.ar..repository.*Repository.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="serviceTransactionManagementAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="repositoryTransactionManagementAdvice" pointcut-ref="repositoryPointcut"/>
    </aop:config>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

**Testing**

To test annotated @Controller method, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861089/testing-spring-mvc-annotation-mapppings/870151#870151) how to

Other than web layer. Notice how i configure a JNDI dataSource in @Before method

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:ar-service.xml", "classpath:ar-persistence.xml"})
public class AccountRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("accountRepository")
    private Repository<Account, Account, Integer> repository;

    private Integer id;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
         DataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver(), "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ar", "#$%#", "#$%#");

         builder.bind("/jdbc/dataSource", ds);
         builder.activate();

         /**
           * Save an Account and set up id field
           */
    }

    @Test
    public void assertSavedAccount() {
        Account account = repository.findById(id);

        assertNotNull(account);
    }

}
```

If you need a suite of tests, do as follows

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(value={AccountRepositoryIntegrationTest.class})
public void ModuleASuiteTest {}
```

web.xml is shown as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:ar-persistence.xml
            classpath:ar-service.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ar</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ar</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>datasource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/dataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

I hope it can be useful. Update schema To Spring 3.0. See Spring reference documentation. mvc schema, As far As i know, is supported just in Spring 3.0. Keep this in mind

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very well explained esp. the convention over configuration part.

Answer (score 7):

Some candidates:

- [AppFuse](https://github.com/appfuse/appfuse) - In AppFuse, the Spring Framework is used throughout for its Hibernate/iBATIS support, declarative transactions, dependency binding and layer decoupling.
- [Equinox](https://github.com/appfuse/appfuse-light) (a.k.a. AppFuse Light) - a simple CRUD app created as part of Spring Live.
- [Spring by Example](http://www.springbyexample.org/) - Various Spring examples plus some downloadable libraries.
- [Tudu Lists](http://www.julien-dubois.com/tudu-lists) - Tudu Lists is a J2EE application for managing todo lists. It's based on JDK 5.0, Spring, Hibernate, and an AJAX interface (using the DWR framework).

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org). It uses Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'll take a look at it. But, I think it's more like a framework built on top of Spring, what I really like to see is some multi-tier web application that's built on Spring.

Comment: I can't help you with webapps. CXF has a lot of examples of Spring app context configuration.