# Exclude Loading of specific properties in Hibernate object

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, criteria

I have a entity class

```
class B{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private A a;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private C c;
```

}

In certain scenarios, I don't want to load object A, since I already have that object.
and same for C also. But these are specific scenarios I don't want to load those objects at all.

is there any way we can tell hibernate not to load certain properties of entity object. {no Eager/Fetch suggestions. I just want this to happen only in specific cases]

Note: I am using Criteria to fetch the object right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `HQL` for your queries, you can specify your [fetching strategy at runtime](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles) based on your condition using the "fetch" keyword, like below:

```
List result = sess.createCriteria(B.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "yourcondition%") )
    .setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .setFetchMode("c", FetchMode.LAZY)
    .list();
```

***Edit:***

Since FetchMode.EAGER and FetchMode.LAZY is deprecated use, FetchMode.SELECT or FetchMode.JOIN

```
List result = sess.createCriteria(B.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "yourcondition%") )
    .setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .setFetchMode("c", FetchMode.SELECT)
    .list();
```

If you want to avoid the SELECT or JOIN check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934753/avoiding-secondary-selects-or-joins-with-hibernate-criteria-or-hql-query).

Comment: can you modify your example according to my class. Sorry I am confused ;)

Comment: I changed. "I just want this to happen only in specific cases" -- What does your specific case looks like

Comment: I might be retrieving B object using A object, in that case I dont need loading of A object in B entity.

Comment: I have done this way 
criteria = getSession().createCriteria(B.class).setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.LAZY)
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
return criteria.list();

Still getting the a object

Comment: I have read online/seen posts that EAGER objects can't be LAZY loaded but LAZY objects can be loaded eagerly  dynamically