# Default formView for SimpleFormController?

Tags: spring-mvc

Firstly I would like to say that I am quite new to Spring (in particular the MVC framework), and just trying to understand how everything works so please go easy on me.

I'm playing around with a dummy application that I've created, and I've created a simple login form that users can access via the /login.html bean. The bean definition is as follows:

```
<bean name="/login.html" class="test.controller.LoginController">
    <property name="successView" value="list_messages.html" />
    <property name="commandClass" value="test.domain.Login" />
    <property name="commandName" value="login" />
</bean>
```

(the `Login` class is a simple object containing a username and password field with appropriate getters and setters).

The `LoginController` class does virtually nothing for now:

```
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController
{
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
    }
}
```

Now I have one view resolver in my bean definition file, which goes as follows:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

To support my Login form I have a login.jsp file in my jsp directory.

My question is as follows: why does accessing /login.html redirect me to login.jsp? I have not specified a formView property for my form, so how does the view resolver know to redirect me to login.jsp?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Joseph.

Comment: why are you using the RedirectView class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not specify The logical view name, Spring relies on [DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html), which **is installed by default**. So if your request is something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/<LOGICAL_NAME_EXTRACTED_BY_VIEW_NAME_TRANSLATOR_GOES_HERE>.html
```

Have you seen <LOGICAL_NAME_EXTRACTED_BY_VIEW_NAME_TRANSLATOR> ??? So if your request is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/login.html
```

The logical name extracted by ViewNameTranslator is **login** which is supplied To viewResolver and Translated To

```
/jsp/login.jsp
```

Nothing else