# Unit test for Spring MVC Controllers that use annotation @RequestParam

Tags: unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc

How can I create a Unit test for Spring MVC Controllers that use annotation @RequestParam? I have created junit tests for controller that uses HttpServletRequest object in the handlerequest method, but I am looking a way to test a controller using @RequestParam.

Thanks

```
@RequestMapping("/call.action")

public ModelAndView getDBRecords(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

   Employee employee = service.retrieveEmployee(id);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861089/testing-spring-mvc-annotation-mapppings

Answer (score 11):

One of the charms of this style of controller is that your unit tests don't need to worry about the mechanics of request mapping. They can just test the target code directly, with no mucking about with request and response objects.

So write your unit test as if it were just any other class, and ignore the annotations. In other words, call `getDBRecords()` from your test and pass in the `id` argument. Remember, you don't need to unit-test Spring itself, you can assume that works.

There is another class of tests ("functional" or "acceptance" tests) that tests the application once it has been deployed (using e.g. WebDriver, Selenium, HtmlUnit, etc). *This* is the place to test that your mapping annotations are doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use 
_request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

and _request.setAttribute("key", "value");

Answer (score 0):

Use integration test (google Spring MVC integration testing)

Kinda this

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = YourApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class SampleControllerTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int port;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void returnsValueFromDb() {
        // you should run mock db before
        String id = "a0972ca1-0870-42c0-a590-be441dca696f";
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/call.action?id=" + id;

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());

        String body = response.getBody();

        // your assertions here
    }

}
```

Comment: Lol didn't figured that question was asked 5 years ago. Anyways, maybe someone find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Try it as your test method !

```
@Test
    public void testgetDBRecords(){
      MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
      mockMvc.perform(get("/call.action?id=id1234").andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
```